# notifyItemChange is Creating additional entries in Data list of RecylerView

Tags: android

I want to delete an item from recycler view but it creates addition entries in Data list related to Recycler View 
Please help

this is the method of onClick() which has to delete Item

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
            int position=getAdapterPosition();
            databaseReference.removeValue();
            CartList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
```

Comment: can you post your adapter class here